# SQL Multiple Table Queries Raw Materials productID ProductName

Tags: sql

Compose a query to calculate the total cost of raw materials for each finish product. In the result table, we would like to see Product_ID, Product_Name, and its total cost of raw materials. Sort the results by the total cost of raw materials in descending order.

Tables that to work with:

**Product_t:** Product_ID, Product_Name, Product_Finish, Unit_Price, On_hand, Product_Description, Product_Line_ID, Work_Center

**Raw_materials_t:** Material_ID, Thickness, Size, Grade, Material_description, Footage_on_hand, Unit_price

I need some help here thanks!

Comment: Welcome to SO! This site is note a code-writing service. Please include what you have tried so far, what results you have gotten, where you are stuck, etc.

Comment: MySQL <> SQL Server. Tag the correct RDBMS.